# core/no-app No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

Tags: flutter, firebase, web-applications

When I try to launch my Flutter Web App with Firebase I get the following error in my terminal

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following FirebaseException was thrown building HomePage(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery]):
[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  HomePage HomePage:file:///C:/Flutter/pbwebapp/lib/main.dart:37:13

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
...
```

I found other people had problems with this error but in my case I have called Firebase.initializeApp() in my `main.dart` file and I have also imported firebase_core in my `pubspec.yaml`

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: "pbwebapp",
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: "...",
      authDomain: "..",
      projectId: "...",
      storageBucket: "...",
      messagingSenderId: "...",
      appId: "...",
      measurementId: "...",
    ),
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Does anyone had this problem with Firebase trying to launch a Flutter Web App?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Solution:** remove name parameter in `Firebase.initializeApp()` method

Answer (score 0):

Use Flutter Fire Cli to add flutter firebase packages like auth, messaging etc,
It will automatically configure all the things for you.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios

Comment: Doesn't change anything unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Okay so somehow removing the name parameter in the `Firebase.initializeApp()` function worked for me. But I dont know why exactly

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).